# Event with 9/10 chance repeating 10 times

Tags: probability

If an event has a 9/10 chance of happening, what is the probability of that event repeating itself 10 times in a row? Do the chances decrease?

Comment: $\left(\frac 9{10}\right)^{10}$

Comment: Do you have a calculator? Start with $(.9)\times (.9) \times (.9) \times....$ with ten factors of 0.9 in all. I did a rough check and get $\approx 0.3487$

Comment: Yes it comes up with 0.348 which I'm assuming is roughly 34%? Or 1/3?

Comment: A bit more than $\frac 13 = .3333$, but for a rough estimate, 1/3 is very close, but 35% better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the probability would be $\left(\dfrac {9}{10}\right)^{10}.$